# ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes

Tags: python, cryptography

**I encrypted the data using cryptography library. Then I stored the file in a binary file which will be used as keystore. I replace the encrypted data in the databased and saved as a different file using the following code**

```
`from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization, hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import base64

# Generate a random encryption key
encryption_key = Fernet.generate_key()

# Generate a password-based key derivation function (PBKDF2) key
password = b'password'
salt = b'salt'
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
    length=32,
    salt=salt,
    iterations=100000,
    backend=default_backend()
)
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))

# Store the encryption key in a key store file
with open('key_store.bin', 'wb') as key_store:
    key_store.write(key)

# Create a cipher suite using the encryption key
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)

# Encrypt the column values
encrypted_values = []
for value in data['place']:
    encrypted_value = cipher_suite.encrypt(str(value).encode())
    encrypted_values.append(encrypted_value)

# Replace the original column with the encrypted values
data['place'] = encrypted_values
`
```

**I tried encoding the data and used the following piece of code to decrypt it and replace the encrypted values with decrypted   **

```
`
import base64

# Read the encrypted data from the CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('encrypted_data.csv')

# Load the encryption key from the key store file
with open('key_store.bin', 'rb') as key_store:
    key = key_store.read()

# Generate the Fernet key from the loaded key
fernet_key = Fernet(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(key))

# Decrypt the encrypted values in the 'place' column
decrypted_values = []
for encrypted_value in df['place']:
    decrypted_value = fernet_key.decrypt(encrypted_value.encode())
    decrypted_values.append(decrypted_value.decode())

# Replace the encrypted values in the 'place' column with the decrypted values
df['place'] = decrypted_values

# Save the decrypted DataFrame to a new CSV file
df.to_csv('decrypted_data.csv', index=False)`
```

**But it gave me the following error: ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.**

Comment: In the encryption part you store the Base64url encoded key. Therefore no Base64url encoding must be done in the decryption part: `fernet_key = Fernet(key)`. It would be different if you would store the raw key during encryption (which would be more resource efficient), then a Base64url encoding would be required during decryption.